# How to kill a NVME M.2 SSD?

Tags: data-storage, ssd

I have an SSD that has completely failed within a week of purchase, unfortunately I have my personal and business info on there. I need to send the drive back for a replacement, however I also need to get my data off the drive or make it non recoverable. With the drive inserted the PC will not even boot to the BIOS (power on and then black screen only) I have 2x M.2 slots and both produce the same results. With the drive removed I can boot fine off a live Linux USB.

How can I kill the drive so the data can't be recovered without visually damaging the device ? Would say 20 volts of the M.2 pins be enough to fry the internals? Hot air and discretely remove some SMD components, short a bunch of pins and then provide power ? The flash chips are covered by a heatsink but I can get to the components on the back (Adata XPG Gammix S50 Lite 2TB).

I totally appreciate that the most fail safe solution is to keep the drive and swallow the loss, but I'd like to explore all my options here. I've killed enough devices by accident so how would you go about doing this on purpose :) Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you apply high voltage directly to the NAND chips? I'm concerned that an attempt to disable the device through the M.2 connector will fry the controller (or some kind of buffer/mux/switch ahead of it) while sparing the actual NAND dies.

Comment: The NAND chips are covered by a heatsink so the pins are hard to reach, I'm worried trying to pry the heatsink off will visually damage the unit

Comment: Most likely if you try to destroy data by applying abnormally high voltages or baking it in the oven makes the warranty void, even if it broke by itself. Better just buy a new one if you are afraid someone might still be able to get your data off it, and use disk encryption on the next drive so the data is unreadable to everyone else without your credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flash chip's data retention time decreases exponentially with increasing temperature. Modern high-capacity multi-level flash is especially vulnerable to this. If you want to erase a flash chip that you can't power on anymore without physically damaging it, bake it for an extended period of time.

A week or so at 100°C (or more, ideally around 120°C) should reliably get rid of the data on that chip.

https://www.electronicspecifier.com/products/communications/meeting-the-challenges-of-next-gen-automotive-designs

Incidentally, this is why high-capacity NAND flash is erased during reflow soldering.

Comment: A term I have heard for SSD is "quantum magnets". Heat ruins these magnets as well. But before you ruin a possibly good drive, can you test it in a second computer? Better safe than sorry. If its truly bad and halts the computer (a short I assume), then its pretty tough for someone else to steal the information off from it.  A good heat soak in the oven should finish the job.

Comment: I've tried it on a different computer with a USB adapter, it's not recognised